# "Look real" or "look realistic"?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Which phrase is correct "the ship model looks real" or "the ship model looks realistic?" 
It seems that according to some dictionary definitions they are both acceptable in this case.

Comment: Actually the ship in the movie does not look real/realistic to to viewer. Also, the alien does not look real/realistic in the movie.

Answer (score 1):

There's a subtle difference in common usage:

"Looks realistic": The observer is fully aware the object is not real.

"Looks real": The observer believes the object is, or at least could be, real.